# Unexpected DotSpatial reprojection results - OSGB36 to 4326

Tags: coordinate-system, dotspatial

I am trying to reproject from OSGB1936 to 4326 using DotSPatial.
I'm doing this as follows ('shapefile' is my loaded shapefile) pulling the source projection from the shapfile which I believe it picks up from the .prj file:

```cs
sourceProjection = shapefile.Projection; 
destinationProjection = ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(4326); 
.
.
double[] test = new double[2];
test[0] = 360216.44430417975;
test[1] = 176543.59223759052;
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(oi, z, sourceProjection, destination, 0, 1);
```

I get the following results:
Before (OSGB36): `360216.44430417975, 176543.59223759052`
After (4326): `-2.5730259372697137, 51.4859574135158411`

When I use online converters I get slight variations but about this:
After: `-2.5743517, 51.4864342`

This puts my points out by a 100 yards or so.

I've tried ignoring the .prj file that comes as part of the shapefile and forcing the projection to OSGB4326, but I get the same result.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this offset?

I tried defining my projection direct from ESRI strings:

```cs
double[] z = new double[2];
ProjectionInfo src = ProjectionInfo.FromEsriString("PROJCS[\"OSGB 1936 / British National Grid\",GEOGCS[\"OSGB 1936\",DATUM[\"D_OSGB_1936\",SPHEROID[\"Airy_1830\",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",49],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-2],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996012717],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",400000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",-100000],UNIT[\"Meter\",1]]");
ProjectionInfo des = ProjectionInfo.FromEsriString("GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"D_WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS_1984\",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]]");
z[0] = 0;
z[1] = 0;
double[] points = new double[2];
points[0] = 360216.44430417975;
points[1] = 176543.59223759052;
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(points, z, src, des, 0, 1);
```

And I'm still getting the same offset as described above.
I'm thinking maybe there is some setting in DotSpatial that is throwing off the conversion here.

Answer (score 1):

This post sorted me out:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426941/proj-4-library-and-osgb36

See the MarkJ answer...It's all to do with datum conversions.

For anyone else in this position here's the code containing the proj4 string with added datum conversion:

```
double[] z = new double[2];
ProjectionInfo src = ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.999601 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84 = 446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894 +units=m +no_defs <> ");
ProjectionInfo des = ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs");
z[0] = 0;
z[1] = 0;
double[] points = new double[2];
points[0] = 360216.44430417975;
points[1] = 176543.59223759052;
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(points, z, src, des, 0, 1);
```

This converts correctly.